# rails pass soap basic auth with savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon, wash-out

I'm trying to send soap request with basic authentication with `savon gem`
My soap server is set up with `wash_out gem`

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController  
     soap_service namespace: 'sir:WashOut', wsse_username: SIRA[:auth][:username], wsse_password: SIRA[:auth][:password]
```

....

When i make a request to soap server via `savon` i get an error:

```
    @client = Savon.client(
      wsdl:  "http://localhost:3000/orders/wsdl",
      soap_header: { 'Username' =>SIRA[:auth][:username], 'Password' => SIRA[:auth][:password] }
    )  

  @response = @client.call(:notify ).to_hash
```

On the last command i get an error

```
 Savon::SOAPFault: (Server) Missing required UsernameToken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this and it works!

```
@client = Savon.client(
  wsdl:  "http://localhost:3000/orders/wsdl",
  wsse_auth: [SIRENA[:auth][:username], SIRENA[:auth][:password] ],
  logger: Rails.logger
)

 @response = @client.call(:notify,  ).to_hash
```

Answer (score 3):

```
client = Savon.client(
           wsdl: 'http://service.example.com?wsdl',
    soap_header: { 
                 "AuthenticateRequest" => 
                                {"apiKey" => "****** your api *********"}}, 
    pretty_print_xml: true)

client.operations

response = client.call(:function)

Note: "apiKey" is my prams to authenticate, your can be different
```

Answer (score 0):

For Savon 2. Basic authorization can be done as follows:

```
@client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "http://localhost:3000/orders/wsdl",
  basic_auth: ["username", "password"]
)  

@response = @client.call(:notify ).to_hash
```