# How can I resolve "unexpected encoding style" using Savon Gem with Ruby on Rails

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, savon

I am getting the following error when accessing a WSDL SOAP server:

```
{:error=>true, :message=>"Savon::SOAPFault: (env:Client) JAXRPCTIE01: caught exception while handling request: unexpected encoding style: expected=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, actual="}
```

I went to [soapclient.com](http://www.soapclient.com/soapclient?template=%2Fclientform.html&fn=soapform&SoapTemplate=%2FSoapResult.html&SoapWSDL=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.yrc.com%2Fdynamic%2Fnational%2FWebServices%2FYRCZipFinder_V1.wsdl&_ArraySize=2) to figure out what it's looking for.

Here is the [error message I'm receiving](https://gist.github.com/thehashrocket/f8ec4dec4d2b0cb49effd85f0387dc50).
Here is the code I'm using to connect to the SOAP client:

```
  my_hash_of_stuff = {
      zipcode: d_zip,
      country: country
  }

  wsdl = 'http://my.yrc.com/dynamic/national/WebServices/YRCZipFinder_V1.wsdl'

  client = Savon.client(wsdl: wsdl,
                        logger: Rails.logger,
                        log_level: :debug,
                        log: true,
                        pretty_print_xml: true,
                        env_namespace: :'soap-env',
                        strip_namespaces: true

  )


  response = client.call(:lookup_zip, message: my_hash_of_stuff)

  print response.to_hash
```

Here's a copy of my [log output](https://gist.github.com/thehashrocket/48c06559d9bed891124a20809b81ec5a) so you can see what's happening.

[This](https://gist.github.com/thehashrocket/a161ee650efa234b1a349b8ba2a9fa7c) appears to be what the SOAP request should look like according to soapclient.com (if i'm understanding it correctly).

[This](https://gist.github.com/thehashrocket/8190a5ab4a0168a2aaf6e54e1916d856) is what I am sending.

I've been fighting with it all day and I'm sure it's probably a combination of my ignorance and something simple that i'm missing. Hopefully you guys might be able to help?

**EDIT 05/25/2016:**
So, looking at this again today, here's the log showing the request that savon is making:

```
HTTPI GET request to my.yrc.com (net_http)
SOAP request: http://my.yrc.com/dynamic/national/webservice/YRCZipFinder_V1
SOAPAction: "http://my.yrc.com/national/WebServices/YRCZipFinder_V1.wsdl/lookupCity", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 417
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://my.yrc.com/national/WebServices/YRCZipFinder_V1.wsdl" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <tns:lookupCity>
      <zipCode>84101</zipCode>
      <country>USA</country>
    </tns:lookupCity>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here's what a correct one looks like. I got this from the existing php app and tested it in Postman to verify that it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://my.yrc.com/national/WebServices/YRCZipFinder_V1.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://my.yrc.com/national/WebServices/YRCZipFinderMessages_V1.xsd" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:lookupCity>
            <lookupCityRequest xsi:type="ns2:YRCLookupCityRequest">
                <zipCode xsi:type="xsd:string">84101</zipCode>
                <country xsi:type="ns2:CountryCode">USA</country>
            </lookupCityRequest>
        </ns1:lookupCity>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**UPDATE:**

After some more hacking, I have my request looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://my.yrc.com/national/WebServices/YRCZipFinder_V1.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://my.yrc.com/national/WebServices/YRCZipFinderMessages_V1.xsd" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <tns:lookupCity lookupCityRequest="ns2:YRCLookupCityRequest">
      <zipCode>84101</zipCode>
      <country>USA</country>
    </tns:lookupCity>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need to get `lookupCityRequest` to move inside `lookupCity` instead of being an attribute of `lookupCity`, however. Testing it in Postman, that appears to be the only stumbling block left to hurdle.

Comment: look on this link...this format may help you.. [stackoverflow.com/questions/28434493](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434493/rails-pass-soap-basic-auth-with-savon/31490846#31490846)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special `:attribute!`symbol to assign additional attributes. That's a functionality from Nokogiri which Savon uses to build XML.

```
require 'savon'

my_hash_of_stuff = 
  { zipcode: "99103",
    country: 'US',
    attributes!: { :country => { 'xsi:type' => 'ns2:YRCLookupCityRequest'},
                   :zipcode => { 'xsi:type' => 'ns2:YRCLookupCityRequest' }}
}


wsdl = 'http://my.yrc.com/dynamic/national/WebServices/YRCZipFinder_V1.wsdl'

client = Savon.client(wsdl: wsdl,
                      # logger: Rails.logger,
                      log_level: :debug,
                      log: true,
                      pretty_print_xml: true,
                      env_namespace: :'soap-env',
                      strip_namespaces: true
)

response = client.call(:lookup_zip,
                       message: my_hash_of_stuff)

print response.to_hash
```

If nothing works and you're desperate enough then you can still create your very own XML and use `xml:` instead of `message:`.

Comment: Hey, Steffen, what is the attributes key you are referring to? I'm looking at the globals page on the repo but don't see it. I tried your suggestion, but it still fails with `"Savon::SOAPFault: (env:Client) JAXRPCTIE01: caught exception while handling request: unexpected encoding style: expected=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, actual="`

Comment: ok, it was a local param, i see. so i just tried that, but it's not placing it where it needs to go. it looks like it needs to go here: `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://my.yrc.com/national/WebServices/YRCZipFinder_V1.wsdl" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` but instead it's putting it in the body.

Comment: so - did it help, did it not?

Comment: no, not really, I ended up writing my own SOAP service to make the queries. I had to do one for each of the services I was connecting to. Sorry.